# Could anyone tell me what could be causing this error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing simple sql queries but for some reason, I keep getting this error 
    "Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
    String or binary data would be truncated.", I have no clue what's causing it and I have searched online what kinds of things would cause this error but all I found was "You are trying to input data that is too long.", which is not the case for my code.

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK
(
    PrimaryAuth     varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Title           varchar     NOT NULL,
    ISBN            varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PubID           char(3),
    Pub_Date        varchar(20),
    price           float,
    book_desc       varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(ISBN),
    UNIQUE(Title)
);

INSERT INTO BOOK values('Scott Westerfeld', 'Peeps', '1595140832', '101', 'September 7, 2006', 8.99, 'A year ago, Cal Thompson...');
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a length on your `title` column as a result your value is being truncated.

Comment: Please write better titles for your questions. This one says nothing about the information you need.

Comment: @JonathanWood Regardless of the question title, this is a basic syntax issue that probably will not help anyone in the future so it should be closed as too localized.

Comment: @bluefeet: Perhaps, but the OP may post questions in the future. He should learn to write better titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Title           varchar     NOT NULL,
```

you need to give varchar a value

i.e.

```
book_desc       varchar(50),
```

So basically the Title column only has a value of 1 character since you did not define it when creating your table and you are trying to insert more than 1 characters inside the column which will give you that error

Comment: God, I must be an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: @user1489599 God isn't listening.